# Applying a function to a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on the movielens dataset, I would like to create a new column by applying a function , the basic idea is :
1) get corresponding movie id from the ratings_dataframe
2)use this movie id to find the name of the movie from moviesdata_frame
3)and copy this value to the corresponding cell in the ratings dataframe

My code consists of:

```
def getname(p):
    nm =  movies.loc[movies['movie_id'] == 'p']['title']
    return nm   



ratings['title'] = ratings.apply(lambda row:getname(gg['movie_id']))
```

The error is :('invalid type comparison', u'occurred at index movie_id')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function for this simple mapping:

```
ratings_dataframe['title'] = \
    ratings_dataframe['movie_id'].map(movies.set_index('movie_id')['title'])
```

Comment: Works like charm.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same without using the set_index function ?